# Time value get increased based on offset in safari browser in JS

Tags: javascript, datetime, safari, timezone, timezone-offset

While parsing the ISO string with new Date() method in safari browser, it will calculated time value based on the client timezone offset. For ex. If we provide the ISO string as "2019-10-17T00:00:00", then it will produces the output "Thu Oct 17 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)". But, chrome displays the correct value like "Thu Oct 17 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530". Is there any issues in the safari browser and how to overcome this issue?

In safari browser: new Date("2019-10-17T00:00:00") => Thu Oct 17 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

In Chrome browser: new Date("2019-10-17T00:00:00") => Thu Oct 17 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530

Comment: More information on the source of this issue on https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/147876/timezone-problems